# is something wrong with my JavaScript code

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a collapse navbar. I was wondering if you guys can check the code because whenever I refresh the website nothing happens and the console does not say any errors are in the code. The HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code are below. I would appreciate if you can look over it and give me feedback so that I can correct my mistake. Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Welcome to my Portfolio</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="index-header">
      <a href="index.html" class="pic-link"
        ><img src="logo/logo.png" alt="" class="pic"
      /></a>
      <section class="container">
        <div class="line-1"></div>
        <div class="line-2"></div>
        <div class="line-3"></div>
      </section>
      <nav class="index-nav">
        <ul class="ul-index">
          <li class="li-index"><a href="" class="a-index">Home</a></li>
          <li class="li-index"><a href="" class="a-index">About</a></li>
          <li class="li-index"><a href="" class="a-index">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="li-index"><a href="" class="a-index">Portfolio</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <main class="index-main">
        <img src="img/banner.png" alt="" class="main-img" />
      </main>
    </header>
    <section id="home"></section>
    <section id="about"></section>
    <section id="contact"></section>
    <section id="portfolio"></section>
    <section id="case"></section>
  </body>
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs="
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</html>
@media screen and (min-width: 360px) {
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .index-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #569188;
  }

  .index-header .pic-ink {
    display: block;
  }

  .index-header .pic {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }

  .index-header .container {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
  }

  .container .line-1,
  .line-2,
  .line-3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }

  .index-header .index-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #569188;
    width: 40vw;
    height: 40vh;
    z-index: 3;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .index-nav .ul-index {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .ul-index .li-index {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }

  .ul-index .li-index .a-index {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #111;
    font-weight: 900;
  }

  .index-main {
  }

  .index-main .main-img {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}


function showNav() {
  let openBtn = document.querySelector(".container");
  openBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelector(".index-nav").style.width = "40vw";
    document.querySelector(".index-nav").style.height = "40vh";
    document.querySelector("index-nav").style.opacity = "1";
    showNav();
  });
}

function hideNav() {
  let closeBtn = document.querySelector(".container");
  closeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelector(".index-nav").style.width = "0";
    document.querySelector(".index-nav").style.height = "0";
    document.querySelector(".index-nav").style.opacity = "0";
    hideNav();
  });
}
```

Comment: please create a code sandbox with the code, then it's easier to help you. codesandbox.io

Comment: You're only calling `showNav()` and `hideNav()` from inside those functions themselves. Don't you see any problem with that? Also every time the event handler is called it invokes those functions again, which means that the same event listener is added, which means the next click it will be executed twice the amount it did as the time before.

Comment: btw, I guess you have a typo in
`document.querySelector("index-nav").style.opacity = "1";` there's a dot missing in the class selector

Comment: @IvanSatsiuk Stack Overflow supports [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993), which can be used to create a runnable snippet. Also we require the necessary code to be in the question, not behind a link. (Although that doesn't mean that you can't have both.)

Comment: @Ivar, thanks, didn't know that

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of things that need attention here. You should enclose the styling and javascript codes inside `<style>` and `<script>` tags if you want to keep them all in one file.

Also, see the modifications to the showNav and hideNav functions.

1. document.querySelector("index-nav") -> document.querySelector(".index-nav")
   The class should be preceded by a `.`
2. `showNav` should call `hideNav` after execution to achieve the toggle event

```js
function showNav() {
  let openBtn = document.querySelector(".container");
  openBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelector(".index-nav").style.width = "40vw";
    document.querySelector(".index-nav").style.height = "40vh";
    document.querySelector(".index-nav").style.opacity = "1";
    hideNav();
  });
}

function hideNav() {
  let closeBtn = document.querySelector(".container");
  closeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelector(".index-nav").style.width = "0";
    document.querySelector(".index-nav").style.height = "0";
    document.querySelector(".index-nav").style.opacity = "0";
    showNav();
  });
}
```

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 360px) {
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .index-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #569188;
  }

  .index-header .pic-ink {
    display: block;
  }

  .index-header .pic {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }

  .index-header .container {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
  }

  .container .line-1,
  .line-2,
  .line-3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }

  .index-header .index-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #569188;
    width: 40vw;
    height: 40vh;
    z-index: 3;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .index-nav .ul-index {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .ul-index .li-index {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }

  .ul-index .li-index .a-index {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #111;
    font-weight: 900;
  }

  .index-main {
  }

  .index-main .main-img {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Welcome to my Portfolio</title>
  </head>

  <body onload="showNav()">
    <header class="index-header">
      <a href="index.html" class="pic-link"
        ><img src="logo/logo.png" alt="" class="pic"
      /></a>
      <section class="container">
        <div class="line-1"></div>
        <div class="line-2"></div>
        <div class="line-3"></div>
      </section>
      <nav class="index-nav" >
        <ul class="ul-index">
          <li class="li-index"><a href="" class="a-index">Home</a></li>
          <li class="li-index"><a href="" class="a-index">About</a></li>
          <li class="li-index"><a href="" class="a-index">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="li-index"><a href="" class="a-index">Portfolio</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <main class="index-main">
        <img src="img/banner.png" alt="" class="main-img" />
      </main>
    </header>
    <section id="home"></section>
    <section id="about"></section>
    <section id="contact"></section>
    <section id="portfolio"></section>
    <section id="case"></section>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @AlmirCampos There are various reasons why people don't explain their downvotes. [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357437) are listed a few.

Comment: The most likely reason here is probably because it doesn't work. At no point are `showNav` and `hideNav` invoked, so neither will ever run. Also even _if_ they were invoked at some point, they still would malfunction because the click event triggers the other function, that then adds _an additional_ event listener, which means that the next click all attached event handlers will fire in a row (the same function will repeat for as many event handlers there are.). The code really don't make any sense.

Comment: Hey guys @Ivar @almir-campos This is my second time trying to answer something on the plaftorm so the discussion helps. I was trying to use what I learn from your original comment on the question @ivar with Stack Snippets. 
If I hit the "run code snippet" button, the nav bar opens and closes. I'm not sure why you say it doesn't work or make sense.
For clarification, the JS piece is invoked inside `<body onload="showNav()">`. I should have included this in my answer.
The logic behind `showNav`and the even triggering works in the snippet. Again, I don't see why you'd say otherwise.

Comment: @AlmirCampos I'm not saying that there is no benefit in explaining why a post is downvoted. But unfortunately, many people don't handle that kind of feedback very well. They see it as some insult and as a result start revenge downvoting the posts of the person who was trying to be helpful by explaining it. For that reason, many users have stopped providing this feedback.

Comment: @EdgardoRodríguez My apologies, I missed that onload. I probably searched for `hideNav` instead and only found it inside the other method and I assumed the same applied for the `showNav`. However the issue with the many event handlers still persists. See [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6w83hy4p/1/). If you open the console you'll see that the more you click, the more these handlers are fired. You'd be better off getting rid of those functions and use an if-else to check if the menu is collapsed. Something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/6w83hy4p/2/).

Comment: @Ivar That makes sense. I was trying to use the original structure but completely missed the mess with the multiples calls.Thanks for taking the time and the Fiddles.